# Session comes null using mockito to test DAO

Tags: mockito

I am using Mockito to do my DAO test, but when I call the method `save` which has a session: `Session session = (Session) getEntityManager().getDelegate();`, but the `session` comes `null`,
I dont know what is happening, someone could help me ??

```
Mockito.when(MyDAOImplMock.salvarOuEditar(object)).thenReturn(object);
objectTest = MyDAOImpl.salvarOuEditar(object);
Mockito.verify(MyDAOImplMock).salvarOuEditar(object);
```

`MyDAOImplMock` is a mock of my DAO implementation, and `MyDAOImpl` is a instance of my DAO implementation.

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public T salvarOuEditar(T entidade) {
    Session session = (Session) getEntityManager().getDelegate();
    session.saveOrUpdate(entidade);
    return entidade;
}
```

Comment: You seem to be confused about what your mock object is going to do.  You have one real instance of your DAO, and one mock instance.  You seem to be checking that when you call a method on the real instance, then the same method is called on the mock instance.  I can't think of any reason why this test would ever pass.  For your question about the `Session`, I will provide you with a good answer, but first you need to clarify how the entity manager returned by `getEntityManager()` gets into the DAO implemetation?  Is it a constructor argument, or is there a setter method?  Please clarify.

Comment: Hello, I solved this problem with @Autowired in my DAO interface instead of create a new instance, and now I've a good coverage, I am going to post the right code.

Comment: Can I post the right code below of the original problem code ??

Comment: If you have an answer, you can post it as an answer.  It's perfectly OK on Stack Overflow to post an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Autowired
private MyDAOImpl myDAOImpl;

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Before
public void init() {
    myDAOImpl.setEntityManager(entityManager);
    objectTeste = new MyObject();
    object = new MyObject();
}

@Test
    public void testSave() {
    objectTeste = myDAOImpl.salvarOuEditar(object);
    Assert.assertEquals(objectTeste, object);
    Assert.assertEquals(object.getId(), objectTeste.getId());
}
```

This way the session is not coming null !
Thanks for all !